# How to pass command line argumets inside Luci openwrt sys.exec() function ?

Tags: ubuntu, lua, openwrt, luci

I want to execute a **sys.exe** function with command line arguments . my code is

```
var1 = "myname"
var2 = "address"
function btn.write()  
   luci.sys.exec("/bin/register $var1 $var2")
end
```

This is wrong i know . How can i pass arguments to a `sys.exe` function in `Luci OpenWrt` ? Any help ? Thanks .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use simple string concatenation:

```
luci.sys.exec("/bin/register" .. $var1 .. " " .. $var2 .. " ")
```